# How to get the first unique character?

Tags: java, hashmap

The below is my code. The question is to find the first unique(The not repeated) character in the given string, I am a beginner to the Java, so right now I am wondering by how to debug the code...... As for my limited knowledge I even don't know how to start to debug...... Thanks!

```
    public class Solution {
        public int firstUniqChar(String s) {
        //My idea without referring to any other solution.
        //put the all character into the hashmap, and delete the key if 
        //there is duplicate value, then get the first key of
        //the remaining map, that is the smallest index of the unique 
        //character;
        Map<Integer,Character> hmap=new HashMap<Integer,Character>();
            int index = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
                //int value=(int)((Integer)map.get(a[i]));
                char charI = s.charAt(i);
                index ++;
                hmap.put(index, charI);
                //Error: cannot find this method;
                while (hmap.ContainsValue(charI)){
                    hkey = charI.getkey();
                    hkey.remove();

                }
                }
        //to return the index of the first key in the hashmap.
        //Error: illegal start of type;
            return hmap.get(hmap.keySet().toArray()[0]);
        }
}
```

Comment: Which tools (IDE) do you use? It depends on the tools how to start the debugger. But you could also try to add test outputs at several places in the program to check the values of variables. Also, why does the method return an int when the result should be a character?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: You should note that `HashMap` does not preserve the insertion order. Getting the first object will not be the first unique character. Use a `LinkedHashMap` instead.

Comment: For alternative approaches to solve your problem, visit here-> http://javarevisited.blogspot.com.au/2014/03/3-ways-to-find-first-non-repeated-character-String-programming-problem.html

Answer (score 0):

In this code you convert string s to char array. Take one char from char array and compare it with all others chars in array. If it is not found(except itself) you break loop and print it. This way you find first unique character in string:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

            String s = "abcd, afsfsfs, abcdef, 90> 20, abeds";
            char[] charArray = s.toCharArray();
            char current = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
                boolean contains = false;
                current = charArray[i];
                int j = 0;
                while (j < charArray.length) {
                    if (charArray[i] == charArray[j] && i != j) {
                        contains = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    j++;
                }
                System.out.println("current=" + current + " " + contains);
                if (j == charArray.length && !contains)
                    break;
            }
            System.out.println(current);
    }
```

Prints:

```
current=a true
current=b true
current=c true
current=d true
current=, true
current=  true
current=a true
current=f true
current=s true
current=f true
current=s true
current=f true
current=s true
current=, true
current=  true
current=a true
current=b true
current=c true
current=d true
current=e true
current=f true
current=, true
current=  true
current=9 false
9
```

Comment: Only answer posts are discouraged. Please explain what you've answered  and why you chose to do it that way.